# I unable to show user name on the page after login session

Tags: php, mysql, session

Good evening guys, I faced some problem in PHP coding. I unable to show the user name on the next page after login even I had already included $_SESSION['username'] and session_start() in my codes. Can anyone help me to point out the problem? The code is as below:

login.php:

```
include_once 'dbconnection.php';
$msg = '';

if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();

    if(isset($_POST['button']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "dashboard.php";
        $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "adminLogin.php";
        $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;

        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$username);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbcon,$password);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE user_name = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,$sql);

        if ($count = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $count['username'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $count['password'];
            header("location: dashboard.php");
            $successmsg = "Successfully Register!";
            echo "<script type ='text/javascript'>alert('$successmsg')</script>";
        } 
            else {
                $errormsg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry.";
                echo "<script type = 'text/javascript'>alert('$errormsg')</script>";
             }

    }

}

?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
//initialize the session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
?>

<!-- User Account -->
<li class="dropdown user user-menu">
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
 <span class="hidden-xs">
   <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>
 </span>
 </a>
```

Comment: have you tried var_dumping $_SESSION to see whats available?

Comment: put session_start() at the top of each script

Comment: Put your session in one of files that are always included, like header or footer, that way session will always be accessable, and try var_dump($_SESSION) and check what will you get

Comment: __never__ store plain passwords in your database! use password_hash() and password_verify()

Comment: I get  array(3) { ["username"]=> NULL ["password"]=> string(3) "xin" ["user_name"]=> NULL } as the result.

Answer (score 0):

some issues with your code:

1. usage of header function: 'location' force a redirect so you should call only exit() after that.
2. check if a session is setted: you should do something like that from php version 5.4:

   ```
   if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
       session_start();
   }
   ```

   use isset for something more specific like:

   ```
   if (isset($_SESSION['username']){
      // do something
   }
   ```